# Is there a way to exchange data between pages with PHP without using SQL?

Tags: javascript, php

I have recently tried to create a multiplayer game using HTML5 Canvas, Javascript, and PHP, but I have not had success using an SQL server. Is there a way to create a global array in PHP that could be accessed and edited by all pages?

Comment: Look up [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: Yes. It's more difficult that SQL.

Comment: his initial question lacked some vital information he wants to create a multiuser chat room so he's looking for a non-sql data store. ie: flat files or a noSQL solution.

Comment: Dave is exactly right.

Comment: In theory I can just use flat files!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$_SESSION`

and put on every page `session_start()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: So I would be able to create a chatroom just by using sesssion?

Comment: I thought sessions were just like localStorage in Javascript?

Comment: sessions are server side with corresponding client side cookie (cookie part is optional) but they are locked to the single user so user 2 couldn't (at least shouldn't!) be able to access user 1's session.  thats why alot of login systems are based on sessions.  You need something that is a global public storage that many users can access. ie : sql :)

Comment: If a session was started any user could for example click to add 1 to a variable, and all the users would see the result of it?

Comment: the other suggestion i got is to write to a local file with unique name

Answer (score 0):

on the top of each page where you want to share this variable start a sessions:

```
session_start();
```

Then  save any variables inside session variables, these sessions will be accessible through the site until the browser is closed.

```
$_SESSION['myArray'] = array("val1","val2","val3");
```

you can access them like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['myArray'][0];
```

Comment: The sessions will be accessible through the site for everybody, or just the user?

Comment: Just the user, each session is created for every user separately